# sh: react-scripts-start: command not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a project that I cannot run `npm start` on.

I haven't touched this project in two weeks. The only thing I did yesterday was add a git repository, that's it.

When I tried to run `npm start` I got this error:

```
sh: react-scripts-start: command not found

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! bk-react-replica@0.1.0 start: 'react-scripts-start'

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the bk-react-replica@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've looked at the solutions on other posts about this same error but none work for me.  I've deleted the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` files, then ran `npm install`.

However, I still get the same error message.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bk-react-replica",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://qhafeezdomain.dreamhosters.com/projects/bkreplica",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.3.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
     "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-scripts-cssmodules": "^1.0.171",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with your `package.json`

Comment: @antzshrek i've added the package.json file

Comment: should `"react-scripts-start"` be `"react-scripts start"`? remove the last `-`

Comment: @davidhu2000 yes, that was the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I will reference you to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49664885/7905714) I provided to a question similar to yours, run this:

```
 npm i -g npm //which will update npm
 rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean // to remove the existing modules and clean the cache.
 npm install //to re-install the project dependencies.
```

Edited:

I just noticed your `package.json` it should be:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
```

not

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-start",
```

Comment: Happy to know that I could be of help to you.