# error with npm start after create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js. And I followed the tutorials in `https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app`. It worked fine while running `npm init react-app my-app`. But I got error when I run `npm start`.

detailed error message: 
[image: error]

[image: error]

I have tried `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app`. That dose not work for me. I also tried move my project folder to upper directory, which still doesn't work.....

Can anyone fix it?

add: package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what's your `npm` version?

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú  6.4.1

Comment: Just npm install in that directory, and see what happens.

Comment: @stevelacerda7 still does not work....

Comment: can you edit above and add your package.json file?

Comment: @stevelacerda7  sure

Comment: What about trying this with a newer node.js version?

Comment: @konekoya  doesn't work

Comment: Can you run the following command and update the output?

`npm list babel-eslint`

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install -g` 
to update npm

then `rm -rf node_modules` to delete the existing modules

finally `npm install` install the new project dependencies