# I cannot run my React JS app with npm from my terminal because the command spawn fails with error ENOENT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Disclaimer before reading: I am new to coding so I hope that I won't be judged too harshly. Anyway, this is what happens right after I run npm-start from my react application root directory:

````
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)

I tried resetting my path variables to point to npm on my windows 7 machine, and still no luck. I've additionally tried reinstalling npm in my react project root and re-configuring my react-scripts dev dependency in the package.json file. Additionally, I've tested this with yarn start, and it still does not work. 

Below is a full error log from Users/MyName/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/some-text-file-debug.log: 

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Mara\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~prestart: app-one@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: app-one@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mara\documents\myprograms\app-one\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Mara\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Mara\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\C;C:\Program Files\Git\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\C;C:\Program Files\Git\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Mara\Downloads\python-3.7.3.exe;C:\C;C:\Program Files\Git\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Ruby\bin;C\php;C\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Mara\documents\myprograms\app-one
10 silly lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle app-one@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: app-one@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid app-one@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mara\documents\myprograms\app-one
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mara\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error app-one@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the app-one@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
````

Comment: ``npm-start`` -  is that what you tried? Have your tried ``npm start``?

Comment: Show us the full code you use in the terminal to start the app

Comment: Are you sure you haven't already started your app on another term?

Comment: My bad, I made a typo. I did npm start, not npm-start. Anyway, the only command I ever write into the terminal is in my root directory at: MyName@admin-PC MINGW64 ~/documents/myprograms/app-one (master)
$ npm start  And no, the app is not already running on another terminal.

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file ?

Comment: Yes, I have a package.json file, and it has the react-scripts, react, react-dom, and node-modules as dependencies.

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app . You may have to follow the steps there and reinstall node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the task is trying to call `require('child_process'). spawn` directly since Windows requires a file extension in order for Node.js to spawn the binary. In this case, you can refer to [npm-execspawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-execspawn) for more information.

Also, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)