# Getting Error while running the React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

This is the log of the error that I am getting while running "npm start" command after creating react app using `npx create-react-app my-app`.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [

1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prestart: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\mechi\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\mechi\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\mechi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mechi\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\mechi\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\mechi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\mechi\my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\mechi\my-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please anyone can give the solution of this problem ? I had tried all the methods that are posted here - uninstalling the `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and reinstalling npm.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm start error with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

1. remove node_modules and lock files
2. edit package.json so the new version of react-scripts is "2.1.8"
3. yarn install / npm install
4. cd your-app
5. yarn start / npm start

Comment: Firstly, I removed package-lock.json and node modules
Then run that "npm install"
Even the same error is coming

Comment: did you follow step 2? before running npm install edit package.json to get new version of react-scripts, try current newer version