# cannot start react app with the npm start command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to run my react-ebay-clone but the

```
npm start
```

command does not work. Instead react throws this error

```
freduah@freduah:~/react-ebay-clone/react-ebay-clone$ npm start

> react-ebay-clone@0.1.0 start /home/freduah/react-ebay-clone/react-ebay-clone
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-ebay-clone@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-ebay-clone@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2020-10-26T19_24_02_415Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~/react-ebay-clone/react-ebay-clone$
```

## Below Is My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-ebay-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you install first? `npm install` ?

Comment: @azium I have run the command `npm install` more than twice

Comment: make sure that you are running the commands in the correct folder. you should see `node_modules` folder with react and all the rest

Comment: @azium I am in current folder but still it isn't working.
I have tried `npm install` again but still it isn't working

Comment: The error is happening in all my react apps

Comment: Try deleting package-lock.json and run npm install again and try with starting the app

Answer (score 0):

I have found this previous stack overflow,

[npm start error with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app).

Comment: Above is my package.json file