# "npm start"ing REACT APP results in compilation error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I am using Windows7 32-bit machine.
Installed node12 v12.22.1, npm 6.14.12

1. created "**npx create-react-app** reacting"
2. **cd** to the **folder**
3. **npm start**

results in opening the web browser adn displaying this message.

```
Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'is-symbol'
Requir

e stack:
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\es-to-primitive\es2015.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\es-abstract\2020\ToPrimitive.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\es-abstract\2020\ToNumber.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\es-abstract\2020\ToInteger.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\array-includes\implementation.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\array-includes\index.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\ExportMap.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\named.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\index.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\getESLint.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\linter.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
    - C:\Users\Sujith\weblearn\js\webBootCamp\react\reacting\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
```

Please help me resolve the resolve the issue and run the app.

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies with `npm install`?

Comment: sounds like there was an error during "npx create-react-app reacting". Other advice is good - run "npm install" or delete node_modules/ and run "npm install". If neither of those work, try recreating the app again with "npx create-react-app reacting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the node_modules and run again npm install.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890/14029804