# Error while running ‘hello-react’ program in react.js

Tags: reactjs

With lots of issues while installing react.js finally when I thought that issues were resolved and everything is in a good place. I found this as a heartache issue.

Error description Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: You used create-react-app to create the app?

Comment: Did you install the project dependencies? (`npm install`) We need a bit more context here.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see this error, it means that something went wrong when you installed the dependencies.
The proper method to fix this error and install all the dependencies again can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app).
A quick workaround can be to install this specific dependency again using the following npm command:

```
npm intall react-scripts start
```

This will help you solve this issue. I still recommend you to install all the dependencies again so that you won't run into such issues later on.

Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: I think it would be a solution!

Answer (score 0):

1. Please execute the below-mentioned command.

   npx i -g create-react-app
2. It takes few minutes and displays a message similar to below

   We suggest that you begin by typing:

   cd your-app-name
   yarn start

   Happy hacking!
3. cd into the your-app-name folder and execute **npm start**

Additional Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: `npx` isn't used to install packages, it's not a package manager it's a package runner, and it's not recommended to install `create-react-app` at all, that's why running it directly via `npx` is the recommended method.