# Error: Missing script "start" running npm start

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the error below when running npm start:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2024-03-28T20_55_38_798Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried the solutions below, and neither worked:

[npm start error with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app)
[Start script missing error when running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Comment: What's in your `package.json` file?

Comment: If only the error message would include a hint...

Comment: The error says to run `npm run` to see what scripts you have. Did you do that? Do you see one named `start`?

Comment: Please provide the content of you `package.json` file. A script inside that file must include a command for `npm start` to work

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't in the proper directory running npm start.